# Error message in graphics.py

Tags: python, graphics

I'm a Highschool Student learning python and I'm a bit stuck on why I am getting an error message in this script. It is supposed to prompt the user for info on how old they are and then return the info in days, hours, and minutes. I'm using the Graphics.py module to accomplish this. The error I am getting is:

```
how old are you.py", line 17, in <module>
    years=entry1.getText()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

I know that the module is properly installed as the getText function works on another script. My code can be seen below. Thanks for any help!

```
from graphics import*

win=GraphWin('How Old Are You?',250,500)
win.setBackground ('Gray')

entry1= Entry(Point(125,100),10).draw(win)
entry2= Entry(Point(125,200),10).draw(win)
entry3= Entry(Point(125,300),10).draw(win)

Text(Point(125,50),'How many years old are you?').draw(win)
Text(Point(125,150),'What month in the year? (number)').draw(win)
Text(Point(125,250),'How many weeks into the month?').draw(win)
Text(Point(125,25),'When done click outside a box').draw(win)

win.getMouse()

years=entry1.getText()
months=entry2.getText()
days=entry3.getText()

totalDays=(years*365)+(months*30)+(days)
totalHours=((years*365)+(months*30)+(days))*24
totalMinutes=(((years*365)+(months*30)+(days))*24)*60

Text(Point(125,350),totalDays)
Text(Point(125,400),totalHours)
Text(Point(125,450),totalMinutes)
```

Comment: If it's a function then why are you calling it as a method?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the `graphics` library you are using, but your error seems to be trying to accomplish too much at once.

You do:

```
entry1= Entry(Point(125,100),10).draw(win)
entry2= Entry(Point(125,200),10).draw(win)
entry3= Entry(Point(125,300),10).draw(win)
```

In each line here, you do create an object - by calling `Entry(...)`, and call a method on that object. The return value of the `draw` method is what ends up stored in the variables.

Usually, in Python objects, methods won't return their object back. If the method does perform an action (like the name `draw` ) suggests, it will usually return `None` - and that is what is happening here, as we see in your error message.

So, all you have to do is to first create your entries, and after that call the `draw` method on them:

```
entry1= Entry(Point(125,100),10)
entry2= Entry(Point(125,200),10)
entry3= Entry(Point(125,300),10)
entry1.draw(win)
entry2.draw(win)
entry3.draw(win)
```

Aside from that, if you don't want your code to be so repetitive, you can create your
entries in a loop and store them in a Python list:

entries = []

```
for vpos in (100,200,300):
    entry = Entry(Point(125,vpos),10)
    entries.append(entry)
    entry.draw(win)

Text(Point(125,50),'How many years old are you?').draw(win)
Text(Point(125,150),'What month in the year? (number)').draw(win)
Text(Point(125,250),'How many weeks into the month?').draw(win)
Text(Point(125,25),'When done click outside a box').draw(win)

win.getMouse()

years, months, days = (entry.getText() for entry in entries)
```